# Nuget package installs but not listed in VS project references

Tags: vb.net, reference, nuget-package

Environment:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
ASP.Net v4.8
Web application project using VB (same problem 2 different projects)
Nuget package Microsoft.Chart.Controls v 4.7.2046 (latest) "ASP.NET and Windows Forms Chart Controls for .NET Framework"

Problem:

The package installs without error.  The folder and content appear in the packages folder.  The entry is listed in packages.config...BUT the reference is not in the References list in VS solution explorer and attenpting to use any part of it causes a lot of html errors eg "Element Chart is not a known element".

Tried "Add Reference" but the package does not appear in any of the lists.

I'm wondering if this package is not intended for use in a web application?

Comment: Are the controls in your toolbox in design view? Maybe they need to be added to the design.

Comment: Mary that has for some reason fixed it - thanks!.  I never use the design view but tried it, sure enough the Chart object appears under Toolbox/Data.  When I add it thsi way and revert to the markup - no errors.  However, the unit still does not appear in References and the code is as far as I can see the same as I entered direct in the markup.  What am I missing?  Nick

Comment: PS how do I mark your response as the answer?